# Is there a way to make a python program wait a few seconds? I am making an infinite number printer but it's too fast to read

Tags: python, python-3.x, wait

I don't know how to make my program wait a few seconds so I can actually read it
Is there a wait function in python or is there a module for such?
I dont have a way to run it in a window because I'm on a school chromebook.

```
My Code:


from random import randint

while True:
    a = randint(0,999999)
    b = randint(0,999999)
    c = randint(0,999999)
    
    if (a <= b) or (a <= c):
        print("variable 'a' has been printed")
        print(a)
        
    elif (b <= a) or (b <= c):
        print("variable 'c' has been printed")
        print(b)
        
    elif (c <= a) or (c <= b):
        print("variable 'c' has been printed")
        print(c)
    
    elif (a == b):
        print("Combo of 'a' + 'b'")
        print(a + b)
        
    elif (a == c):
        print("Combo of 'a' + 'c'")
        print(a + c)
    
    elif (b == c):
        print("Combo of 'b' + 'c'")
        print(b + c)


How to make it wait?
```

Comment: Search the documentation for “sleep”

Comment: Also your second condition has a mismatch between the text “variable c” and function print(b)

Comment: Pipe your output to a pager like `less`. You wouldn't want to pause if you were just redirecting the output to a file, so let the consumer control the pace of scrolling, not the producer.

Comment: If it is an infinite number printer then it is probably printing too slow. You'll never get to infinity at that rate.

Answer (score 1):

use sleep(), it takes its arguments in seconds.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
while True:
    a = randint(0,999999)
    b = randint(0,999999)
    c = randint(0,999999)

    
    if (a <= b) or (a <= c):
        print("variable 'a' has been printed")
        print(a)
        sleep(1)
        
    elif (b <= a) or (b <= c):
        print("variable 'c' has been printed")
        print(b)
        sleep(1)
        
    elif (c <= a) or (c <= b):
        print("variable 'c' has been printed")
        print(c)
        sleep(1)
    
    elif (a == b):
        print("Combo of 'a' + 'b'")
        print(a + b)
        sleep(1)
        
    elif (a == c):
        print("Combo of 'a' + 'c'")
        print(a + c)
        sleep(1)
    
    elif (b == c):
        print("Combo of 'b' + 'c'")
        print(b + c)
        sleep(1)
```

You'll need to import it from time as I have above.

Alternatively, it will be more efficient and maintainable if you have just one sleep() at the end of the while loop instead of several sleep() fucntions. Below is a much better example of the code above. Thank you to Max for the suggestion.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
while True:
    a = randint(0,999999)
    b = randint(0,999999)
    c = randint(0,999999)


    if (a <= b) or (a <= c):
        print("variable 'a' has been printed")
        print(a)
    
    elif (b <= a) or (b <= c):
        print("variable 'c' has been printed")
        print(b)
    
    elif (c <= a) or (c <= b):
        print("variable 'c' has been printed")
        print(c)

    elif (a == b):
        print("Combo of 'a' + 'b'")
        print(a + b)
    
    elif (a == c):
        print("Combo of 'a' + 'c'")
        print(a + c)

    elif (b == c):
        print("Combo of 'b' + 'c'")
        print(b + c)

    sleep(1)
```

Comment: It would be much easier to put one sleep at either the top or bottom of the whole loop.

Comment: Sorry, I some how read it has him having a bunch of functions not average if and elif statements. Will update the code to be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce sleep in your code wherever you need to wait.

```
import time

time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds
```

Link to the documentation [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)